# Orthonormal basis self-adjoint matrix

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the matrix which for some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb R$ is given as
$$ A:=\begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \beta & -\alpha \end{pmatrix}.$$

This matrix is self-adjoint and correspondingly has real eigenvalues $\pm \sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}.$

The eigenvectors are then given by

$$\left(\frac{\alpha \pm\sqrt{\alpha^2+\beta^2}}{\beta}, 1\right).$$

However, they are not orthonormal. Is there an easy way to get orthonormal eigenvectors?

Comment: Gram-Schmidt would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues will be distinct if and only if $\alpha,\beta$ are not both equal to zero. When $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, the eigenvectors will automatically be orthogonal which means that it is sufficient to normalize the eigenvectors. We note that
$$
v = (\alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}, \beta) \implies\\
\|v\| = (\alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2})^2 + \beta^2 = 2(\alpha^2 + \beta^2) \pm 2\alpha \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}.
$$
When $\beta \neq 0$, these we have $\|v\| \neq 0$. So, the normalized eigenvectors will be given by
$$
\frac v{\|v\|} = \left(\frac{\alpha \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}}{2(\alpha^2 + \beta^2) \pm 2\alpha \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}}, \frac{\beta}{2(\alpha^2 + \beta^2) \pm 2\alpha \sqrt{\alpha^2 + \beta^2}} \right).
$$
In the case that $\beta = 0$, the matrix is diagonal, which means that $(1,0),(0,1)$ is an orthonormal set of eigenvector.